# C++ template class recursively required from

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to code the Horner alogrithm using a meta programming code. Unfortunately the code doesn't compile. Here you find the compiler error:

```
In instantiation of ‘const int tuple_nth_element_v<1u, int, 1>::value’:
----> LINE 1 <---- recursively required from ‘const int tuple_nth_element_v<2u, int, 2, 1>::value’
required from ‘const int tuple_nth_element_v<3u, int, 1, 2, 1>::value’
----> LINE 2 <---- recursively required from ‘constexpr const double Horner_Impl<5, 2ul, int, 1, 2, 1>::value’
required from ‘constexpr const double Horner_Impl<5, 3ul, int, 1, 2, 1>::value’
required from ‘constexpr const double Horner<5, int, 1, 2, 1>::value’
required from here
incomplete type ‘tuple_nth_element_v<0u, int>’ used in nested name specifier
```

The code used the following:

```
template<unsigned int N, class T, T... t>
struct tuple_nth_element_v;

template <class T, T t0, T... t>
struct tuple_nth_element_v<0, T, t0, t...> {
    static const T value = t0;
};
template <unsigned int N, class T, T t0, T... t>
struct tuple_nth_element_v<N, T, t0, t...> {
---> LINE1 <----
    static const T value = tuple_nth_element_v<N-1, T, t...>::value;
};


template<int x, std::size_t i, class T, T... a>
struct Horner_Impl
{
----> LINE 2 <----
    constexpr static double value = Horner_Impl<x, i - 1, T, a...>::value * x + 
    tuple_nth_element_v<sizeof...(a) - i, T , a...>::value;
};

template<int x, class T, T... a>
struct Horner_Impl<x, 0, T, a...>
{
    constexpr static double value = tuple_nth_element_v<sizeof...(a), T , a...>::value;
};

template<int x, class T, T... a>
struct Horner
{
    constexpr static double value = Horner_Impl<x, sizeof...(a), T, a...>::value;
};
```

Someone would have an idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This way seems a little bit more straightforward to me because it takes one coefficient off the pack on each recursion instead of using a helper class to perform an indexed enumeration:

```
#include <iostream>

template <int x, typename T, T a_n, T ...a>
struct Horner {
    constexpr static double value = Horner<x, T, a...>::value * x + a_n;
};

template <int x, typename T, T a_n>
struct Horner<x, T, a_n> {
    constexpr static double value = a_n;
};

int main() {
    double y = Horner<3, int, 5, 3, 2, 8>::value;
    std::cout << y << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `tuple_nth_element_v`, you recursively scroll through the parameter pack until `N == 0`, when `N` is the number of elements in the parameter pack. When `N == 0`, you can't have any elements in the parameter pack. The specialization for `N == 0` requires at least one element in the parameter pack, and so it can't be selected. The only one that matches is the un-specialized class, which has no definition.

With `Horner<2, int, 1, 2>`, there is a series like this:

```
value = tuple_nth_element_v<2, int, 1, 2>::value = tuple_nth_element_v<1, int, 2>::value = tuple_nth_element_v<0, int>::value;
```

That last instantiation is the source of the error.

I'm not familiar with the algorithm, but I think your solution is to change

```
template <class T, T t0, T... t>
struct tuple_nth_element_v<0, T, t0, t...>
```

to

```
template <class T, T t0, T... t>
struct tuple_nth_element_v<1, T, t0, t...> //N is now 1, not 0
```

and in `Horner_Impl`, change

```
constexpr static double value = ... tuple_nth_element_v<sizeof...(a) - i, T , a...>::value;
```

to

```
constexpr static double value = ... tuple_nth_element_v<sizeof...(a) - i + 1, T , a...>::value; //note the + 1
```